# How do I set a minimum time between the start of an ajax request and its success?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Basically, sometimes the AJAX calls in my application are too fast and I need to delay some of them. I have a "progress/loading" icon and when it comes to the fast AJAX calls the icon appears and disappears too quickly. I need a way to set a minimum time for an AJAX action to finish (**or at least to appear that way**). Here's my generic `ajax` function that I use in my application.

```
var app = {
    ajax: function (paramObject) {
        $.ajax({
            url: paramObject.url,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: paramObject.method || 'GET',
            data: paramObject.data || '{}',
            success: function (jsonResponse) {
                if (paramObject.success) {
                    if (paramObject.successDelay) {
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            paramObject.success(jsonResponse);
                        }, paramObject.successDelay);
                    } else {
                        paramObject.success(jsonResponse);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

As you can see I have a `paramObject` which takes some parameters like: `url`, `method`, `data`, `success` and `successDelay`. Currently, the AJAX call takes its time and when it finishes it takes in consideration the delay (`successDelay`) that I've set. But that's not really what I wanted. What I want is to track the delay between the start of the AJAX call and its end/success so the whole thing takes a minimum of `successDelay` milliseconds.

EDIT to further explain:

In essence I want to make it seem as though the AJAX call takes longer. And it needs to happen in the function I have above.

Comment: Why do you want this? It seems a little annoying for the user that you would slow down the system just so that an icon is shown for a longer period of time. Why not make the icon appear for slightly longer, regardless of how long the request takes?

Comment: Don't delay the ajax. Make the animation longer to complete.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan `Why not make the icon appear for slightly longer, regardless of how long the request takes?` This is exactly what I'm attempting. The request will not be delayed, only the success callback which later inadvertently updates my UI.

Comment: @Mikel I'm attempting to delay my success action only. Not the AJAX request.

Comment: Ok, but there's no need to do this when you can, for example, make the duration of $.fadeOut animation longer.

Comment: @Mikel My success function (`paramObject.success`) is what changes my UI. Moving the functionality towards my UI code is just going to clutter it. And the UI code is not just a progress icon showing up but a lot more complicated so I'm trying to keep it as clean as possible.

Comment: @Alternatex I see what you mean. Check my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[EDIT]

Without understanding your code, I think this is what you want :

```
var app = {
    ajax: function (paramObject) {
        var timeStart = Date.now();
        $.ajax({
            url: paramObject.url,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: paramObject.method || 'GET',
            data: paramObject.data || '{}',
            success: function (jsonResponse) {
                if (paramObject.success) {
                    if ((Date.now()-timeStart) < paramObject.successDelay) {
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            paramObject.success(jsonResponse);
                        }, paramObject.successDelay - (Date.now()-timeStart));
                    } else {
                        paramObject.success(jsonResponse);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

Don't delay the AJAX, just check if you remove the waiting animation class with or without a delay :

```
// before the AJAX call
var timeStartMs = Date.now();

// On the success block, we check if more or less than 500ms
// and we remove the '.waiting' class
if(Date.now() < timeStartMs + 500) 
    setTimeout(function(){ $('.target').removeClass('waiting'); }, 500);
else
    $('.target').removeClass('waiting');
```

Like this :

```js
var timeStartMs;

function f() {
  // before the AJAX call
  var timeStartMs = Date.now();

  var ping = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2000) + 1;
  $('#target').addClass('waiting');
  $('#target').html('Lag : '+ping);
  // fake AJAX call :
  setTimeout(function() {
    if (Date.now() < timeStartMs + 500)
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('#target').removeClass('waiting');
      }, 500);
    else
      $('#target').removeClass('waiting');
  }, ping);
}
```

```css
.waiting {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="target">Click</div>
<button onclick="f()">run</button>
```

Comment: Not really a direct answer to my question but definitely pushes me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested it, but I believe it does what you want.

```
var app = {
    ajax: function (paramObject) {
        var $d;
        if (paramObject.successDelay) {
            $d = $.Deferred();
            setTimeout(function() {
                $d.resolve();
            }, paramObject.successDelay);
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: paramObject.url,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: paramObject.method || 'GET',
            data: paramObject.data || '{}',
            success: function (jsonResponse) {
                if (paramObject.success) {
                    if (paramObject.successDelay) {
                        $d.done(function(){
                            paramObject.success(jsonResponse);
                        });
                    } else {
                        paramObject.success(jsonResponse);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I accepted Blag's edited answer 10 minutes before you posted :/

Comment: @Alternatex You can always upvote,though,  if you find an answer useful